# Preference Manager and Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and would appreciate some help please.

In the onCreate method of my main activity I have this:

```
    // set the default preferences
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.preferences, false);

    // get the preferences
    prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Load the values or defaults from the SharedPreferences
    msMainClockStart = prefs.getLong( "Main_Clock_Minutes", 0 );
    useShotClock = prefs.getBoolean( "Use_ShotClock", false );
    msShotClockStart = prefs.getLong( "Shot_Clock_Seconds", 20000 );
    tvPeriodPrefix = prefs.getString( "Period_Prefix", "P" );
    valMaxPeriods = prefs.getInt( "Max_Periods", 4 );
```

In my res/xml/preferences.xml file I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="Main_Clock_Minutes"
    android:positiveButtonText="SAVE" 
    android:negativeButtonText="CANCEL" 
    android:title="Main Clock (minutes)" 
    android:defaultValue="480000" 
    android:summary="How many minutes for the main clock."/>

<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:key="Use_ShotClock"
    android:title="Enable Shot Clock"
    android:defaultValue="true"/>

<EditTextPreference 
    android:key="Shot_Clock_Seconds"
    android:title="Shot Clock (seconds)" 
    android:summary="How many seconds for the shot clock." 
    android:defaultValue="30000"/>

<EditTextPreference 
    android:key="Period_Prefix"
    android:title="Period Prefix (e.g. Q, Shift, Period)" 
    android:defaultValue="Q"/>

<EditTextPreference 
    android:key="Max_Periods"
    android:title="Maximum number of periods" 
    android:defaultValue="4"/>
```

For some reason the defaults are not getting read/loaded from the xml file.  The defaults that are entered in the getLong() method or getBool() method that are being used.

Does anyone know why?

EDIT @Gunnar Karlsson

After changing to `getDefaultSharedPreferences` I'm getting an error at line 121 which is this one:

```
msMainClockStart = prefs.getLong( "Main_Clock_Minutes", 0 );
```

The Error says "cannot cast from a long to a string.  But msMainClockStart is a Long and prefs.getLong() returns a Long so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the preferences with

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

use

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

to retrieve the preferences, not `getPreferences()`

Comment: Thanks for that @Gunnar Karlsson.  I have edited my original post with an error message that I'm not getting.

Comment: prefs.getLong(...) throws a ClassCastException if there is preference which is not a long. Did you try to print the value if you use prefs.getString("Main_Clock_Minutes",0)?

Comment: Try to print it where/how?

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't work.  I had to getString and then cast it into a Long.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use PreferenceManager I discovered two options.  The first is that I could create a preference subclass or the other was to save it as a string and then cast it into a Long.

Here is the code:

```
    // set the default preferences
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.preferences, false);

    // get the preferences
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context );

    // Load the values or defaults from the SharedPreferences
    msMainClockStart = Long.valueOf( prefs.getString( "Main_Clock_Minutes", "0" ) ) * 60000;
```

This worked perfectly.